# How to pass bloginfo(url) in a jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I need help in getting this to work, i want to pass the site url in a jquery window.location.replace("URL") 
And i want it to work like this window.location.replace("site_url/contact-us")
My whole concept is to redirect to www.mysite.com/contact-us but am getting www.mysite.com/login/contact-us

Here is my full code

```
// PHP
// Add the javascript file only if user is logged in and page id login
     if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'login' ) ) { 
      wp_enqueue_script( 'java_reload', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/java-reload.js', array('jquery'), '201951218', true );
}

//JAVASCRIPT
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

      window.location.replace("/contact-us"); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a relative URL.

```js
window.location.replace("/contact-us");
```

If that code was run on any page on `example.com`, it would redirect to `example.com/contact-us`

Comment: I tried that but it won't work that way since the code is not in homepage, example if you run the code on example.com/login you will get something like this example.com/login/contact-us and such page does not exist

Comment: I don't think so: https://www.loom.com/share/40bb6938893e43e6ba0d5ef2ee3939d6

Comment: Is not an issue of thinking, i tried it and the result was example. com/login/contact-us

Comment: @pandglobal Would you mind sharing more of your code? The video I attached (which you didn't watch) shows that it does work. Make sure that you include the leading `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from PHP to Javascript using [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).

### PHP

```
// Add the javascript file only if user is logged in and page id login
if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'login' ) ) { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'java_reload', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/java-reload.js', array('jquery'), '201951218', true );
    $data['url'] = get_bloginfo( 'url' );
    wp_localize_script( 'java_reload', 'wpse365632_data', $data );
}
```

### Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // wpse365632_data will contain the PHP data sent to JS.
    window.location.replace( wpse365632_data.url + "/contact-us");
});
```

...*however*, for your particular use case, is there a compelling reason to not use [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)?

eg,

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'login' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/contact-us' );
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: am using wp_redirect which works fine but the user needs to reload the page after login before the wp_redirect can work since is server base, so i was thinking JavaScript which is a client side can do it. You cold above for jquery redirect works, though my concept is to redirect the user automatically to a contactus page immediately he loggins in